# isEmpty doesn't work

Tags: vba, vb6

I have an user interface in which there is a "from-to" list. When I test it, I let the list empty, I don't insert any data in it.

But when calling `isEmpty`, it returns that it is not empty which is wrong.

This is my code snippet:

```
 Dim oFromToList As Object
   Dim vList As Variant

   Set oParameters = SmartContext.Parameters 
   If oParameters.Contains("smartFromToList1") Then   
        Set oFromToList = oParameters.Item("smartFromToList1")
        vList = oFromToList.GetList
        If Not IsEmpty(vlist) Then
        MsgBox "not empty"
        Else
        MsgBox "empty"
        end if
   End If
```

The name of the list is **smartFromToList1**, it is empty but the messages shown is "not empty"

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code

Answer (score 2):

You're mis-using the [IsEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445044(v=vs.60).aspx) function. It is used to check that a variant type variable has been initialized. Meaning whether or not the variable has been assigned a value. It cannot be used to check an object.

The line `vList = oFromToList.GetList` initializes the vList. It assigns what ever is returned by GetList to vList.

You do not say what kind of object oFromToList is so we can't tell you how to do your test. Depending on what GetList actually returns there may be a `Count` property you can check, or possibly test

```
vList Is Nothing
```

.

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty just checks if a variable is initialized. You just Dim vList as a Variant so I'm not sure what data you are expecting in it. If it's meant to be some kind of array, list, collection, etc. then it's possible that vList is initialized but doesn't contain any items. What type of object is it? Are you able to do anything like If vList.Count > 0 Then?

Comment: It isn't just initialized. I load data in it:  `Set oFromToList = oParameters.Item("smartFromToList1")
        vList = oFromToList.GetList`

Comment: I'm still not clear what the issue is. I'm not sure what type of control/object smartFromToList1 is and what GetList is supposed to return. From your comment it sounds like you are expecting it to contain data in which case it wouldn't be empty but in your original question you say that is shows "not empty" which you're not expecting.